# Can Splash/PhantomJS (for JavaScript rendering) work with Wget for downloading a webpage?

Tags: python, bash, scrapy, phantomjs, wget

For wget, in many cases it just return “Turn of your javascript to continue”

I’ve found some articles says python’s scrapy with Splash/PhantomJS can rendering, but I’m not familiar with programming even with python, so if there has some solution that can integrate with wget it will be perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `wget` only. But you can with a little [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) script:

```
$ phantomjs dl_page.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions > stackoverflow.html
```

**dl_page.js**:

```
const system = require('system');
const page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Splash's HTTP API](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#).

To get the rendered HTML, use the [`/render.html` endpoint](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-html), passing the URL as argument, and optionally with some `wait` parameter:

```
wget -qO- 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://www.example.com/&timeout=10&wait=0.5'
```